# Make asset pipeline act like production on development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I am experiencing some problems with assets on *production*: missing ones, stuff compiled into the wrong files (javascript for "/admin" getting compiled into the frontend code and so on). Most of the assets come from engines. I want to debug and optimize this.

For that, I need to precompile, serve and fail on my *development environment* just like it is done on *production*.

I have added some lines to my `config/development.rb`:

```
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.precompile += %w( store/all.js store/all.css admin/all.js admin/all.css ) # @TODO: clean up, and optimize.
  config.assets.compile = false
```

Running this with `rake RAILS_GROUPS=assets RAILS_ENV=development assets:precompile` gives me all the assets and the `manifest.yml` in `public/`.

But then the server fails:

```
Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError in Spree/home#index

Showing /xxxx/app/views/spree/shared/_head.html.erb where line #13 raised:

favicon.ico isn't precompiled
```

**favicon.ico isn't precompiled**. But it is! Its there, in the public dir, in `manifest.yml`, and I can fetch it with the browser (or wget): http://localhost:3000/assets/favicon.ico.

**NOTE** Favicon is simply the first asset called. If I strip out favicon, the problem simply surfaces with the next asset, being "all.js", or, when that is stripped, "all.css", and so on. I can strip it untill "footer_bg.png", and it will then fail there. Again: the problem is not favicon, but the fact that the *development* environment does not see the precompiled assets at all.

What more is needed to get *development* asset pipeline similar to *production*?

EDIT: More explicit explanation that favicon is not the problem, merely a symptom.

Comment: What is your production environment stack?  Single Server/Multi-Server, Apache/Nginx, Heroku?  Are you deploying using capistrano and using the capistrano recipe?  Are you using config.serve_static_assets = true in production?  Have you tried handling serve_static_assets through apache/nginx instead of within Rails as recommended by Rails?

Comment: My production stack is pretty much a black-box Passenger. It is a site5 vhost. I am not deploying with capistrano, but with a git-push && post-commit hook (aka git-deploy). `config.serve_static_assets = true` is disabled. I have tried serving assets trough Apache, yes. It solves little. As the problem I try to solve here, is my **development** environment not serving my assets like on production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up installing an apache, passenger on localhost to troubleshoot.

Apache (could probably be any passenger-able server) because of the static asset serving. 
Furthermore, on localhost I can bump the verbosity of apache in its logs very high, offering me enough debug information.

Passenger to emulate the ruby version and the gem-loading as much as possible as on production.

Running on webrick is just too different, even when emulating as close as possible, it proved too different from a production stack; which is why I could not reproduce the production problems in there,

Firing up the whole stack as if it were production allowed me to troubleshoot. Which lead me to conclude that several problems were causing the asset-woes: a gems assets not being picked up; a permission issue (compiled assets not readable by www-data) and a few assets not being compiled properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to leave `favicon.ico` in `public`...

```
alzabo0:~ $ rails --version
Rails 3.2.3
alzabo0:~ $ rails new ojoijoijo
[...]
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/index.html
      create  public/robots.txt
[...]
```

Comment: Maybe. But that is beside the point. Problem is not favicon.ico, problem is that my development env. won't recognise compiled assets, like I want it to. And since I chose to run favicon trough the asset pipeline (long story), it is the first file being included and simply an example of where the asset pipeline chokes. If I move the favicon out of the pipeline, like you suggest, the asset pipeline will choke a few lines further down, on some css or js file.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but try adding to your precompile list:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( store/all.js store/all.css admin/all.js admin/all.css favicon.ico)
```

Comment: That works indeed. Strange thing, is that on production this is not needed. And since this line is one of the main things that I want to clean, fix and optimize, this is exactly the part that should be "just like on production".

Comment: strange indeed. perhaps on production, if you "rake assets:clean" it suddenly won't work there either? How do you reference favicon.ico in your view template? Personally, I don't use helpers to generate the favicon.ico link. You are using favicon_link_tag? It's such a oddball thing, maybe leave it in dev for now and move on to the interesting bit?

Comment: Please note that favicon *is not the problem*. The problem is that my development env won't recognise assets when precompiled. Favicon *is simply an example*. When I leave favicon out, the problem remains, and will surface with the next asset: a js or css file.